# How to use notepad++ and regular expression to replace mm.anytablename with mm.anytablename collate DATABASE_DEFAULT

Tags: regex, notepad++

currently

mm.* how about the space, it search "mm.table where ..."

i only want to replace mm.anytablename with mm.anytablename collate DATABASE_DEFAULT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find

```
( mm\.)(\w* )
```

Replace

```
\1\2COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Mind the space.

You could always refer to http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
/mm\.\S+/anytablename/
```

Comment: i mean it end with space, after . can be any table name so need *, it is not only start with mm

Comment: This regex will work for file name such as mm.tabe_1 also ... and you can use (mm\.\S+) and replace with \1COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT